# Counting subsets whose elements are ordered

Tags: probability, combinatorics

To count Straight Flush we need to count hands like $2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ and $10, J, Q, K, A.$ The number of all such hands is $4 \times 10.$ That means there are $10$ sets of cards with strict ordering. How do we know there are $10$ of those?

There are $\binom {13}5$ subsets. How do we distill out the number of subsets with strict ordering out of $\binom {13}5$ subsets if that's what we do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no need to involve binomial numbers. If you have a set like
$$\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$$
the number of chains with $k$ elements ($k\le n$) is simply $n-k+1$, because $n-k+1$ is the greatest possible value for the beginning of the chain, and a chain is uniquely determinated by its initial element.

The formula does not work for poker, because in poker the ace can be the least and the greatest card. For poker put $n=14$.